# IndexedDB error: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

```
console.log(db); //db object exists
console.log(db.objectStoreNames.contains('test')); //true - object store exists

var transaction = db.transaction(['test'], 'readwrite'); // this line is causing the error

A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations." code: "6
```

Why am i getting this error? My db and objectstore exists? I'm loosing my mind! :D Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, I know this is not the easiest thing in the world with IndexedDB, but if you can post a self-contained test case that exhibits this problem, you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: answered in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182320/indexeddb-error-a-mutation-operation-was-attempted-on-a-database-that-did-not-a#comment16425991_12251397)

Answer (score 4):

One potential cause of this error: Firefox does not support IndexedDB in private browsing windows. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1639542 and https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/issues/81.

Comment: As per the bugzilla link, this will be fixed in Firefox 115

Answer (score 1):

I just try now on chrome, safari on Mac os x and found no error.

I do as follow on http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/using/schema.html (the page load ydn.db.Storage object)

```
schema = {stores: [{name: 'test'}]}
st = new ydn.db.Storage('test1', schema)
// ... wait for async
db = st.db()
db.transaction(['test'], 'readwrite')
```

old chrome use 1 instead 'readwrite', but i don't think it a reason.

Comment: Thanks but i found the error: I didnt wait for my objectstore to get created before i did transactions.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many such errors incurred.Only this article http://dev.opera.com/articles/introduction-to-indexeddb/ shows why-----
" **With IndexedDB, every operation or transaction on our database must occur within a callback function**."

This is my simple example,please check it using chrome's devtool->resource->indexedDB;(if nothing in indexedDB,try refresh browser)

html section:

```
<form id="form1">
    <label for="task">What do you need to do?</label>
    <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Save entry</button>
</form>
```

script section:

```
var idb = indexedDB.open('niangzi10', 2);
    var dbobject; // Define a global variable to hold our database object
    idb.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        console.log("success");
        if (dbobject === undefined) {
            dbobject = evt.target.result;
        }
    }
    idb.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
        dbobject = evt.target.result;
        if (evt.oldVersion < 1) {
            dbobject.createObjectStore('tasks', { autoIncrement: true });
        }
    }
    //transaction operation in callback function
    var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
    form1.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
        'use strict';
        evt.preventDefault();

        var entry = {}, transaction, objectstore, request;
        entry = { name: document.querySelector("#task").value };

        // Open a transaction for writing
        transaction = dbobject.transaction(['tasks'], 'readwrite');
        objectstore = transaction.objectStore('tasks');
        // Save the entry object
        request = objectstore.add(entry);
        transaction.oncomplete = function (evt) {
            alert("'" + document.querySelector("#task").value + "'has been insert into indexedDB;please check it using chrome's devtool->resource->indexedDB(if nothing,refresh browser)；");
        };

    });
```